# How to get a binding point of an image variable in OpenGLES

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I am trying to obtain a binding point of an image variable in my GLES shader. I can do this for uniforms or shader storage blocks using that code:

```
GLenum Prop = GL_BUFFER_BINDING;
GLint Binding = -1;
GLint ValuesWritten = 0;
glGetProgramResourceiv( GLProgram, GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK, i, 1, &Prop, 1, &ValuesWritten, &Binding );
```

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as `GL_IMAGE_BINDING`. In desktop GL, I am just getting the location of the image uniform using `GetUniformLocation` and then bind it to an image slot using `glProgramUniform1i`. Unfortunately in OpenGLES, `glProgramUniform1i` can be used for sampler uniforms only and does not work for image uniforms. The reason I need this binding point is because I am doing automatic resource binding. My resources can be associated with a uniform variable name. I want them to be automatically assigned to the right image slot. That works fine so far for all resources except for images on GLES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image unit is the value of the image uniform variable. While the ES 3.1 spec does not allow *setting* values for these variables with `glProgramUniform1i()`, there's nothing I can see that prevents you from *getting* the value that was set in the GLSL code with the `binding=...` layout qualifier.

This is based on section 7.10 "Images" of the spec. On page 112, it says:

> The value of an image uniform is an integer specifying the image unit accessed.

and in the same section on page 113:

> The location of an image variable is queried with GetUniformLocation, just like any uniform variable.

Therefore, to get the image unit for variable "MyImage" in program `prog`:

```
GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "MyImage");
GLint imgUnit = -1;
glGetUniformiv(prog, loc, &imgUnit);
```

This gives you the image unit that the image variable in the shader is bound to. If you wanted the image name, you can continue the querying:

```
GLint imgName = -1;
glGetIntegeri_v(GL_IMAGE_BINDING_NAME, imgUnit, &imgName);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. I used to work with DX for years and new to OpenGL, so some things confuse me a lot. Image binding unit query turned out to be very different from getting uniform buffer binding and looks to me a bit like a backdoor.

Comment: Images are much more similar to textures/samplers. The main difference is that you can set texture/sampler bindings with `glUniform1i()`, but not image bindings. There was actually a version of the spec that said you could, but it was edited out (still there, but with strike through). The revision history references a Khronos bug, which I was unable to find in the public bug database. I would have liked to see **why** they removed it. Maybe they just considered it redundant once you can specify the binding in the shader code.