# GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D for glBindImageTexture?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, texture2d, opengl-4

Is there a function to get the currently bound image texture?

I can get the currently bound texture for `glBindTexture` with `glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, &bound_texture);`.

**Does something similar exist for `glBindImageTexture`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **§ 8.26.1** Image Unit Queries
>
> The state required for each image unit is summarized in table `23.45` and may be
>   queried using the indexed query commands in that table. The initial values of
>   image unit state are described above for `BindImageTexture.`

The enum you probably want is `GL_IMAGE_BINDING_NAME`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not exactly sure how to use the command, could you possibly make an example of the glGet command I would need to execute?

Comment: @JanRüegg You need `glGetIntegeri_v`. Actually, [this question is pretty much a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409680/how-to-get-a-binding-point-of-an-image-variable-in-opengles).